# Google Sheets ArrayFormula to Compare Multiple Cells from Different Rows

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, count, array-formulas

I'm making a checklist of Disney Blu-rays. Some Disney movies are available in 4K but some are not. I'm trying to create a column that will show if a movie release is available in a higher quality than the entry for that row.

Here is a simplified test sheet that should hopefully make my goal more clear...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2-npiEdTE9ardDi2q38sYhkKRFKAPCu_gtJFbOZa80/edit?usp=sharing

I've found a ton of ways to compare rows, look for duplicates, etc. But despite my limited but best efforts, I can't find a way to combine what I've found in a way that works towards this goal. The best I've been able to do is find duplicate titles but I've not been able to compare that against the Original Theatrical Release Year, and Blu-ray vs 4K release columns.

I'd like to do this through an ArrayFormula so that any rows I add are easily and automatically rendered into the formula without any extra work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(a, b, c, d, LAMBDA(x, IF(a="",,
 IF(IFERROR(x, "No")="No", "Yes", "No")))(VLOOKUP(a&d, 
 {FILTER(FILTER(a&d, b), NOT(COUNTIF(FILTER(a, c), FILTER(a, b)))); 
  FILTER(FILTER(a&d, c),     COUNTIF(FILTER(a, b), FILTER(a, c)))}, 1, )))
 (A3:A&B3:B, C3:C="Blu-ray", D3:D="4K", ROW(B3:B)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That solution worked great! Unfortunately, I changed my sheet to a quantity based version. (See 2nd tab of test sheet) I was kind of able to adapt your code but switching to a quantity broke it and I can't quite figure out how to adapt it fully. Basically, I need it to look for a number >0, or maybe easier, just look for <>"". Can you take another quick look if you get a chance? Thank you again!

Comment: It's been a while, but I was able to adapt to your code to my quantity version of the list. If you do happen to see this, would you mind taking your look at what I'm trying to do next? Thanks again! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76783949/

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFS(A3:A="",,COUNTIFS(A3:A,A3:A,B3:B,B3:B,D3:D,"4K",ROW(A3:A),">"&ROW(A3:A))*(D3:D<>"4K"),"Yes",1,"No"))
```

I'm not sure if I fully understood the task but the above formula seems to give the correct result.

Comment: It does indeed seem to work. Thank you!

Comment: when looking for duplicates, do you want to only look at the rows that come after that entry? And should we take into account the year of release when looking for duplicates? If the answer to both of these questions is no. The formula can be simplified to: `=ArrayFormula(IFS(A3:A="",,COUNTIFS(A3:A,A3:A,D3:D,"4K")*(D3:D<>"4K"),"Yes",1,"No"))`

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to compare rows both before and after... and it needs to take into account the year. It looks like your work on the test sheet works except in a specific scenario where there is a 4K version but no Blu-ray version. Also, I changed my sheet to a quantity based version. (See 2nd tab of test sheet) I was able to adapt your code but the same problem still exists in that specific scenario. Thanks again!