# Google Sheets ArrayFormula to Compare Multiple Cells from Multiple Different Rows

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, lambda, array-formulas

I'm making a checklist of Disney Blu-rays. Some Disney movies are available in 4K but some are not. I'm trying to create a column that will show if a movie release is available in another edition in a higher quality format than the current entry for that row.

I've already received some help and made some progress from an earlier post here...
[Google Sheets ArrayFormula to Compare Multiple Cells from Different Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74904565/)
...But I've made some additions that I would really appreciate some further help with.

The following goals might not make a lot of sense so here is a simplified test sheet that should hopefully make it all much more clear...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2-npiEdTE9ardDi2q38sYhkKRFKAPCu_gtJFbOZa80/edit?usp=sharing

1. Improving Current 'Upgrade Available' Formula:
   I'm looking to expand on what I already have to factor DVDs into it. And I would like zeros "0" and blank cells to both be treated as a zeros.
2. Adding a Formula for Another Comparative Column:
   Finally, I'd like to add a column for showing when other editions are available in the same quality format.

I'd like to do this through ArrayFormulas so that any rows I add are easily and automatically rendered into the formula without any extra work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain little more based on your expected result on `Column R`? How these yes and no are coming?

Comment: I was looking at your sheet, can you please clarify the condition. for 1, what is the condition for it to say yes or no.

Comment: @Harun24hr Column R is just manually filled in at the moment. Basically it means... is there another edition released on the same quality format? For example, there might be a Diamond Edition and Signature Edition both on Blu-ray which means that "Yes", there is another Blu-ray quality format listed. But if one of those examples was a 4K release (even if the 4K release also included a standard Blu-ray disc) then "No", there is not another release on the same quality format. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Logan for 1), it basically means... Is there another edition (besides the one listed in this row) that has been released in a higher quality format? For example, if the one listed in the current row is a Blu-ray, but there is also an edition of the same movie in 4K, then "Yes", there is a higher quality release available. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm thinking it might actually be nice if I added another column before the quantity columns to signify if it was a 4K, Blu-ray, or DVD release. Would that make it easier?

Comment: I added a new sheet tab called "Added Column Version" and added in the new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have two suggestions to test:

Case 1:

```
=LET(qtlist,BYROW(E3:G,LAMBDA(each,MAX(FILTER({3,2,1},each)))),MAP(B3:B,D3:D,qtlist,LAMBDA(title,year,qt,IF(title="","",IF(MAX(FILTER(qtlist,B3:B=title,D3:D=year))>qt,"Yes","No")))))
```

Case 2:

```
=LET(qtlist,BYROW(E3:G,LAMBDA(each,MAX(FILTER({3,2,1},each)))),MAP(B3:B,D3:D,qtlist,LAMBDA(title,year,qt,IF(title="","",IF(COUNTA(FILTER(qtlist,qtlist=qt,B3:B=title,D3:D=year))>1,"Yes","No")))))
```

Basically, they work by creating a ranking of qualities, filtering by the numbers in those columns. In case 1 it compares to the maximum, in which case it's true if there's a bigger value; and in case 2 it finds if there's more than one equal

Comment: This looks like it may have done the trick! Thank you! I'll look at it better when I get home but can it be adapted into an ArrayFormula that can go in Row 2? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, just put something like `={"Write your header here";LET(........)}` and the formula will be placed with the header in that formula

Comment: I'm thinking it might actually be nice if I added another column before the quantity columns to signify if it was a 4K, Blu-ray, or DVD release. Would that make it easier?

Comment: I added a new sheet tab called "Added Column Version" and added in the new column.

Comment: The first part of the function is basically that column: =BYROW(E3:G,LAMBDA(each,MAX(FILTER({3,2,1},each))))

Comment: You manually wrote a column of that information? In the first place, you're duplicating your work just for writing it and that you'll have to always be cautious not to forget to update that column if anything changes in the other three. And, secondly, 4K, BR and DVD will also have to be translated somehow to numbers in order to categorize them from higher to lower quality; so you wouldn't have a much smaller formula finally

Comment: Yes, you're corrected. There will be a little bit of duplicate information there by having that column. I guess another reason why I was thinking about adding it was because if people are contributing to the list and they don't know the disc quantities, they can just add the main classification there and the number of discs can be added later.

Comment: If I may suggest some "workaround" for that case, is to ask them to use some "ridiculous" amount like 99 or 999 in that corresponding column. The formula will keep working and with conditional formatting -as you already know how to do- you find all the rows that have that value, or anything higher than 90 for example

Comment: Sorry. I really should have made that addition before I posted all of this.

Comment: I can set up conditional formatting to blackout disc quantity columns that will be unused based on the format. For example, if it's a Blu-ray (BD), it'll black out the 4K quantity column. And I can add some kind of color to columns that will expect quantities to be entered.

Comment: I changed the formulas contemplating your new column, changing the BYROW part with `BYROW(E3:E,LAMBDA(each,XMATCH(each,{"DVD","BD","4K"})))` - they're to the right in each of the cases in the new sheet. Please be aware that you should post a new question if your scenario changes in the future

Comment: Thank you so much. I should have figured that out before I posted. Heading out again so I'll look at all again when I get home. Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you again for your help! Our users have asked for one last change so if you are feeling up to it, please take a look here if you get a chance... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76797284/last-step-for-a-google-sheet-arrayformula-to-compare-multiple-cells-from-multipl -Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

*[Here's another approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2-npiEdTE9ardDi2q38sYhkKRFKAPCu_gtJFbOZa80/edit#gid=739563674) strictly based on **Column_B** `Movie Title` + **Column_D** `Release Year` + **Column_E** `Release Format`*

***1) Available in a Higher Quality Format?***

```js
=map(B3:B,D3:D,E3:E,lambda(b,d,e,if(b="",,if(e>vlookup(b&d,sort({B:B&D:D,E:E},2,1),2,),"Yes","No"))))
```

***2) Other Edition Available in Same Quality Format?***

```js
=map(B3:B,D3:D,E3:E,lambda(b,d,e,if(b="",,if(countif(filter(E:E,B:B&D:D=b&d),e)>1,"Yes","No"))))
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a minimal and elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you again for your help! Our users have asked for one last change so if you are feeling up to it, please take a look here if you get a chance... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76797284/last-step-for-a-google-sheet-arrayformula-to-compare-multiple-cells-from-multipl -Thank you again!